# SKSpriteKit - repositioning a moving object when didBeginContact is called

Tags: iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Currently, I have a box(size of the iPhone that has a ball bouncing in it.  When it hits the boundary of a wall, it bounces back as expected.

Now what I want to do is when the ball is going to the left and hits the left wall, I want it to appear on the right side and to continue going to the left. Also, if the ball moves right and hits the wall on the right then it should appear on the left still going right.  (Like the old Asteroids game)

I thought that I could use didBeginContact and simply change the position.  Problem is that changing the position using setPosition: doesn't actually change it.  If I use the moveTOx:, which does work, the problem then is that the ball can't be moved to the right edge because of the call to didBeginContact on the right side gets called and it gets moved back to the left side.

The balls should move smoothly from one edge to the next.  Perhaps didBeginContact is not the correct place to do this.

Any suggestions? I can't imagine this is a unique problem...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (https://github.com/macshome/RockBuster/tree/master) and here it is:

```
// Create a method to be called from the update:
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    [self updateSpritePositions];
}

// In your method, iterate through your objects and set the position:
- (void)updateSpritePositions {
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"ball" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

        //  Get the current position
        CGPoint nodePosition = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y);

        //  If we've gone beyond the edge warp to the other side.
        if (nodePosition.x > (CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + 20)) {
            node.position = CGPointMake((CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - 10), nodePosition.y);
        }

        if (nodePosition.x < (CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - 20)) {
            node.position = CGPointMake((CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + 10), nodePosition.y);
        }

        if (nodePosition.y > (CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + 20)) {
            node.position = CGPointMake(nodePosition.x, (CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - 10));
        }

        if (nodePosition.y < (CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - 20)) {
            node.position = CGPointMake(nodePosition.x, (CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + 10));
        }

    }];

}
```

Comment: You could generalize the code by using the node's size property instead of hard coding the values.

Comment: for sure, thanks for the suggestion.  Once I get this working perfectly, I'll do just that.